# Googlephpapi managing users with service account

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-directory-api

I've followed the directions here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts

I've added the scopes for the client id of my service account within the admin console of

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.customer
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.domain
```

The following is the code I'm trying to run

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=JSONFILELOCATION');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setApplicationName("Directory");
$client->setScopes(array(
   Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_CUSTOMER,
   Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER
));
$client->setSubject("directory@directory-152416.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
//$client->setSubject(SUPERADMINEMAILADDRESS);

$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
 // Print the first 10 users in the domain.
$optParams = array(
   'domain'=>'MYDOMAIN',
   'maxResults' => 10,
   'orderBy' => 'email',
);
$results = $service->users->listUsers($optParams);
```

The result I get is unauthorized client

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
"error": "unauthorized_client",
"error_description": "Unauthorized client or scope in request."
}
' in /var/web/composer/googlephpapi/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118
Stack trace:
#0 /var/web/composer/googlephpapi/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(94): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#2 /var/web/composer/googlephpapi/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(181): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /var/web/composer/googlephpapi/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(58): Google_Task_Runner->run()
#4 /var/web/composer/googlephpapi/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(781): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request),  in /var/web/composer/googlephpapi/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118
```

I'm trying to use the service accounts email address.  But I get the permission error.  If I use a Super Admins email address I get results just fine.  Is there a setting I'm missing to be able to use the service account?  I thought doing domain wide delegation would allow me to use the service account to have full access without using a real user.

Comment: Being the fact that the service account is not a super admin, that is why you are getting unauthorized `client`. You can only use a service account to **impersonate** a user. Therefore, the subject should always be the super admin of the account.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example to try.

```
   define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array( Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER ) ));

   putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $path_to_json_creds_file );

   $client = new Google_Client();
   $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();  // loads whats in that json service account file.
   $client->setScopes(SCOPES); // adds the scopes
   $client->setSubject($domainUserWithAdminRoles);  // An org account with special roles defined.

   $dir = new Google_Service_Directory($client);

   // get the account.
   $results = $dir->users->get($userKey);

   print_r($results);
```